# how to transfer data from one server to another dynamically..?

Tags: sql-server

I have many linked servers that contains similar databases, Now i am asked to make a stored procedure to transfer data from database of one sever to another server's database. but I am supposed to give the destination server name, source server name, destination database name, souce database name as parameters to the stored proc.
I am able to do it between different databases of the same server using dynamic sql.

```
    SET @dynsql =N'INSERT INTO '+@destinationDBname+N'..UIElement (UIElementID,UIElementName)
    SELECT @LatestUIElementId,UIElementName  
    FROM '+QUOTENAME(@sourceDBname)+N'.dbo.UIElement WHERE UIElementID = @OldUIElementId'
    EXEC sp_executesql @dynsql,N'@LatestUIElementId int',@LatestUIElementId =@LatestUIElementId
```

but unable to  find a way which can be used between servers.

Comment: So your above query does not work when you simply append the linked server to the front of your dynamically generated object name? If not what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing destination server in your query. From what I see above you only have destination database.

Query for destination server should look like this

```
select * from [Server].database.schema.table
```